# I am seeing a suprice result from Integer comparing

Tags: java

I am seeing different results in checking Integers against another and i cant figure out why i am reciving these results?

For example:

```
    Integer j = new Integer(2);
    Integer i = new Integer(2);

    boolean test1 = false;
    if(i >= j){
    test1 = true;
    }else{
    test1 = false;
    }

    boolean test2 = false;
    if(i <= j){
    test1 = true;
    }else{
    test2 = false;
    }

    System.out.println("i >= j: " + test1);   //gives True
    System.out.println("i <= j: " + test2);   //gives False

    System.out.println(i >= j);  //gives True
    System.out.println(i <= j);  //gives True
```

I was curius as to why i am seeing that i is greater then j so i also tested i > j and still seeing a True as result.

I wonder if someone can explain this to me, or tell me where i can read up on this. I have tried to figure it out and have been reading into wrapper classes but not sure that is the culprit. Stack placement maybe?

Comment: `if(i <= j){
    test1 = true;`. Should be `test2 = true`. Also you could simply do  : `boolean test2 = i<= j;`

Comment: Double-check where you've written `test1` and where you've written `test2`...

Comment: This is a great example of why you should limit the scope of your variables and encapsulate functionality in methods or entirely different classes wherever applicable.

Comment: YES! oufff...guess i staired my self blind on this! As you say Tom, i need to rethink and control my scope! Gracias amigos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a typo: in the second block, you wrote `test1 = true`, but it should be `test2 = true`.

Comment: Indeed.  However, this question is therefore best dealt with via the new "simple typographical error" close reason.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks! I wasn't aware that there was a "typo" close reason. I have put in my close vote.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth haven't seen that one yet. All glory to the new close reason! Also, to hypnotoad.